# Can I use Xcode, FileMaker Pro, and Excel Sheets work together to make a native iOS app?

Tags: database, excel, xcode, filemaker

Thank you for taking the time to help a guy out.

So, our client has a directory of niche businesses and we are working to turn this directory into a native iOS application for iPhones.  Is it possible to take my client's Excel sheets, put them onto FileMaker Pro, and then put that into Xcode?

Your input, direction, and advice on this topic of database management will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

FileMaker Pro has native import of Excel files, they could be auto-converted into tables in FileMaker during the import. FileMaker also has [FileMaker iOS API](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/14/en/appsdk/) which allows you to create an iOS app from FileMaker file using Xcode. Using it does require membership in the FileMaker and Apple developer programs.

If you need more details, you need to look into the manual and do a bit of research. If you get stuck, ask further questions with particular problems.